# Access Material Table DataSource from component.ts

Tags: angular-material

I'm dealing with a custom wrapper (not mine and I can't refactor) around a Material table. I've been asked to implement a feature that requires accessing the paginator, sort, and filter. Is this possible, or am I stuck with my implementation using a mat-table without the custom wrapper? If it matters: I'm trying to update the dataSource records that are displayed on the paginator's currently selected page.

Partial code:

```
    @Component({ selector: 'custom-table' })
    export class CustomTable {
        @Input customDatasource: any[];
        // dataSource for mat-table
        ngOnInit() {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.customDatasource);
```

And in the calling view component:

```
    <custom-table [customDatasource]="mydataset"></custom-table>
```

And what I'd like to do from the calling component:

```
onSomeButtonClick() {
    const foo = dataSourceOfCustomTableElement; // This is what I'm struggling with
    const page = foo.paginator.page;
    const filtered = foo.filterData(mydataset);
    // etc...
```

Comment: What is the issue here..? are you not getting the data when you pass from here: `[customDatasource]="mydataset"`

Comment: @Tushar: The data binding works fine. The problem: Let's say the user has applied a sort and filter and is on page 1 of a 20 item page size table. When the user hits a button, I want items 1-20 to be updated, but not the rest of the underlying dataset.